# Set custom UIButton frame using NSLayoutConstraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

So I'm using this custom UIButton class: https://github.com/victorBaro/VBFPopFlatButton

And in the documentation, the author used this example.

```
//Example
self.flatRoundedButton = [[VBFPopFlatButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 150, 30, 30)
                                          buttonType:buttonMenuType
                                         buttonStyle:buttonRoundedStyle
                                         animateToInitialState:YES];
self.flatRoundedButton.roundBackgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.flatRoundedButton.lineThickness = 2;
self.flatRoundedButton.tintColor = [UIColor flatPeterRiverColor];
[self.flatRoundedButton addTarget:self
                       action:@selector(flatRoundedButtonPressed)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:self.flatRoundedButton];
```

Since `buttonType` is a get-only property, I can't just create a `VBFPopFlatButton` instance and then assign the type, i.e. I have to assign the type when I create the instance. I was just wondering if there is a way to initialize without having to explicitly set the frame (using  `CGRectMake`) because I want to use constraints later to set the button's frame.

OR

If there is a way to overwrite `CGRectMake`, after the initialization?

Comment: i think you need to change VBFPopFlatButton 's implementation

Comment: As per my understanding, Do you want to change the origin(x and y), size (height and width)?

Comment: Yes, so based on the documentation and implementation, I have to set the frame when I initialize a `VBFPopFlatButton`. It seems like the constraints that I added later on do affect the origin and size of the button, but it looks like `CGRectMake` and the constraints are interfering with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VBFPopFlatButton` doesn't have a `buttonType` property. It has a `currentButtonType` property, which is read/write, so you **can** assign the type later.

Anyway, just set the frame to `CGRectZero`. Then turn off `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`:

```
self.flatRoundedButton = [[VBFPopFlatButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero
    buttonType:buttonMenuType buttonStyle:buttonRoundedStyle animateToInitialState:YES];
self.flatRoundedButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

Then you can add whatever constraints you want to the button.